# Cookie mode session state not updated though aapcmd utility

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-2-configure-asp-net-settings) for updating a session timeout in a site configuration. I tried multiple combination as well. Also, tried this suggestions given at [thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1156509.aspx) which did not work either.

I am trying this command,

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set config site_name /commit:WEBROOT /section:sessionState /cookieless:UseCookies /cookieName:ASP.NET_SessionId /timeout:520
```

*Applied configuration changes to section "system.web/sessionState" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/site_name" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/site_name"*

shows above output. But, actual value is not replaced as shown in below,
[image: sessionState_timeout]

Details:
IIS Web server7.5
Windows Server 2008 R2

Can someone help in this regards. Thank you.

Comment: I have also tried your codes on my side and it works well. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGsFF.png). I suggest you could check you have used right site name and try again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: Oh.. okay let me debug further from my side. Thank you so much for confirming.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: Thanks again. It has resolved and tested. Only thing was /commit:WEBROOT isn't required in IIS 8 below.
Working fine with my automation script.Glad for your help.